# To what degree is the research output of abstract topics related to funding for institutions?

Tags: research-process, mathematics, physics, statistics

I am trying to evaluate how much truth the statement has "Research output is proportional to the amount of funding the institution gets". On the extreme end I see it is absolutely true because for certain research like that of chemistry, quantum computing etc, research would be  really hindered without the researchers having access to actual facilities for conducting experiments and such.. but what about for those abstract topics like pure mathematics or theoretical sciences, do the research output of such topics also depend on the amount of
funding which institutions relating to them gets?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The statement is too strong as it posits an exact relationship that doesn't exist. But it is true that funding and (quantity and quality) of research output are positively correlated.

But there are many other factors. In the US, most R1 (research) universities are also strong in teaching, especially undergraduate education. Some large state universities have over 40,000 students, mostly undergraduates. That all gets funded, both from tuition and from tax revenue.

A lot of research also means a lot of grant writing and grant funding, both from private and government (tax) sources.

And, specifically for math, the undergraduate program is very important, so funding is arranged somehow. And mathematicians also apply for and get grants.

The university, especially a research university, is a very complex place with a very diversified mission. Research funding is an important part, but not the only factor.

Comment: (+1) Where I was, fees paid by undergrads (and parental units) were much higher than tuition: fees remained on campus, but tuition went into state coffers. Fees really paid the bills. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

This is not a complete answer, but if you don't have any research funding, you have to make a living in some other way. In many cases -- at smaller, not so research active universities, for example -- that means that people have to teach more than at those universities where people have more research funds. As a consequence, people without research funding also have *less time for research*, and that affects their productivity.